# How do I pass a string property with spaces to a Spring Cloud Data Flow task?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When I launch a task using the shell, I can't seem to use spaces within a property for my boot application.

```
task launch my-task --arguments "--app.username=alpha beta gamma"
```

When my code prints out the value of `username`, it is `alpha` and not `alpha beta gamma`.

My Spring configuration code looks like the following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class CustomTaskProperties {
private String username;
   ... getters and setters ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape whitespaces by adding single quotes around the property value

Try this:

```
task launch my-task --arguments "--app.username='alpha beta gamma'"
```